# werkzeug.routing.exceptions.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'signup_events'. Did you forget to specify values ['hashedEventid']?

Tags: python, html, flask

I can't open up my events page without this error popping up. I can't figure out what to do with hashedEventid. What should I do?

HTML

```
        <!-- Sign up Button (for members) -->
        <div class="push">
            <!-- Utilise my hash id functions on ur own pls thx -->
            <a href="{{ url_for('signup_events', hashedEventid=object_id_to_hash(object_id=event.id, act='event')) }}" role="button" class="egioesigseions">Sign up</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Python

@app.route('/events/signup/', methods=["GET","POST"])
@login_required
def signup_events(hashedEventid):

```
if not isinstance(current_user, Members):
    return jsonify({'error': 'Unauthorized, only members can sign up'}, 401)

eventid = id_mappings.hash_to_object_id(hashedEventid)
if eventid is None:
    return jsonify({'error': 'id does not exist'}, 404)

print(eventid)
event = Events.query.get(eventid)
user = current_user

signup = SignUp(request.form)
signup.name.data = user.name
signup.email.data = user.email
signup.eventid.data = event.name

# eventss = Events.query.all()
# events_list=[(i.id, i.name) for i in eventss]
# signup.eventid.choices = events_list

if request.method == "POST" and signup.validate():

    if signup.name.data != user.name and signup.email.data != user.email and signup.eventid.data != event.name:
        return jsonify({'error', 'Unauthorized attempt to modify read only fields'}, 404)

    signup = SignUps(name=signup.name.data, email=signup.email.data, eventid=eventid)
    db.session.add(signup)
    db.session.commit()
    db.session.close()
    #
    # signup_id = signup.id
    #
    # attendance = Attendance(signup_id=signup_id, event=signup.eventid.data)
    # db.session.add(attendance)
    # db.session.commit()
    # db.session.close()
    return redirect(url_for('events'))

return render_template('eventssignup.html', signup=signup, event=event, user=user)
```

I tried simply changing the object_id = event.id, but it simply doesn't work